# Items to review counter on the top bar does not update

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, top-bar

At least for me, on http://askubuntu.com, the top bar highlights the number of items in the "Suggested Edits" queue (whenever there's something to process).

However, the counter does not update after items are processed. First world problem: after processing the queue, I click it just to find "There are no items for you to review."

Obviously, it's really minor, but as almost everything on Stack Exchange updates automatically, that probably could too.

Comment: The number never goes down, it was always like that. (unless of course you refresh)

Comment: But well, should it?

Comment: Good question. Think it should but live refresh counters never decrease so it won't be consistent.

Comment: I guess it shows the total number of pending flags you have responded to. Anyway, unless a moderator respond to these flags either by disputing them or accepting them, then they will show. If you click on the counter, you will find a link that will show the pending flags you have responded to.

Comment: @MIH I'm not sure we're talking about the same counter. When I click the counter, it goes to suggested edits. And those typically do not relate to any flagging I have done in any way.

Comment: @Olli indeed we are talking about different counters :) sorry :)

Comment: @MIH that's cool - good to catch it early.

Answer (score 6):

Suggested edits are not live refreshed.  Percentage-of-users wise, it's not information important enough to send that delta out to in realtime.  Every realtime notification has cost, it needs to be hooked into every update mechanism and we have to publish and send a message via websockets to *every* user for any global counter like that when it happens.  It's just not worth it.

Think about what's updated currently, all of them are *for you*, relevant *to you*.  Your inbox, your reputation, your badges.  A suggested edit number changing isn't directly relevant *to you* and isn't worth the cost of publishing, many users may even find it annoying.

Basically I don't see us changing this, it's not intended to update realtime.  To have an idea of scale here, this is a screenshot taken like 8 seconds ago of **concurrent** websocket connections to our network:

[image: Concurrent websocket connections to Stack Exchange]

...that'd be *a lot* of extra messages for not much benefit.

Comment: So, the answer is "no, it shouldn't, at least for now". Thanks. Instead of real-time, it could update after finishing a review task. The next task is loaded using AJAX, so the page is not refreshed.

Comment: It's not very helpful to users. Clearly the *Suggested Edits* queue display does get updated sometimes. It's too bad that it can't be updated as a user might expect. Seems like a user interaction could be enough to force an update. IOW, instead of talking about automatic realtime updating, couldn't the user action of accessing the menu (again) trigger an update?