# Take filters into account for the Suggested Edits review counter

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, top-bar, filtering

The review queues allow you to set up a tag filter, so we can filter our personal queue regarding our knowledge and/or preference.

I'm a bit confused by the review counter in the top bar. It can show up when there are items to review, but when clicking on it, it's possible there's nothing to review because of the filters I'm using:

[image: Review screenshot]

Wouldn't it be better to show how many items are in the queue that fit our tag filter, instead of all of them?

**Edit:** A same behaviour might be required when the limit of daily review is reached. Then, the review counter seems to be useless. Wouldn't it be better to hide the counter in this particular case?

[image]

Comment: I understood what you mean but it's not written clearly. Will see if I can edit, also it might be a dupe, let me search...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I knew that, this is why my last sentence was here - You can edit my question, naturally.

Comment: That number is cached [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218489/167646) [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213042/167646), I don't think this will be implemented.

Comment: That's answering a different question, @Stijn.  The request is that the number displayed reflect the number of items that pass your filter, not that it update.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg My point is that this can only be done if they stop caching it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is to do with filtering. I get this same problem and I have no filters. It's the caching as already referred to.

Comment: @Stilly.stack You're probably right, I didn't think about this and when it is 1% remains, you can just "skip" if the question exceeds your skills.. However this widget can be interesting ^^

Comment: @Stijn Then, it would be heavy to add this feature.. As you linked, this will not be implemented because there is not much benefit. I mean, do we know how many people use this?

Comment: @Stilly.stack If you don't know the subject matter, you will not be able to judge whether the post needs modifications other than the spelling and grammar mistakes; that's important because if so, the suggestion should be rejected.  Since you can't tell, you should not perform the review.  I use a filter so I don't even see them.

Comment: [Unlikely to happen before this is fixed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109634/230957)

Comment: Indeed, whatever we want to do with this feature, there is no way to improve it, because this is too heavy and cached for all SE users, isn't it? @3ventic